# Setting up Tomcat to direct /<some>/<path> to /index.html

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I've got a WAR deployed to / which contains, for example:

```
index.html
js/script.js
images/image.png
```

I want to be able to map requests for existing resources (like the js and images) to the actual files as normal, and then respond to other requests (say /some/path, /, or /somepath) with index.html. Ideally, I want to do this without rewriting the URL.

Is this possible with a servlet or JSP? I've been unable to find any doc or worked example for this scenario so far... any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Make your somepath an actual folder and put a index.html in it? Have that index.html redirect to a ../index.html  but why would you be using html rather than jsp anyway?

Comment: Switching out the index.html for a JSP would be fine - but I'm not clear how to define the servlet URL to match any sub path...

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't really a JSP/Servlet way of doing things. Its very ASPish. Why would you want every path to go to one file?

Comment: I want to handle multiple different types of visitor, defined by the URL, but catch them all on the same initial page. Looks like the default servlet should be able to do what I need but haven't been able to get it working yet... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800725/configure-web-xml-tomcat-5-for-one-servlet-to-handle-all-incoming-requests]

Comment: You're trying to simulate url rewriting without using rewriting. The problem is rewriting maps different path parts to variables, and your approach doesn't.  So say `/es/whatever/` vs `/en/whatever/` with rewriting, you would map the first folder bit to be a language parameter. With your approach, you're going to have to parse the url yourself, if you can get it to work at all.

Comment: In fact, your approach will not work.  Because you'll be redirecting, which means, you can no longer parse the original url.  Just use a real rewriting filter.

Comment: Thanks - I've gone the rewriting route as you suggest. Tuckey.org's [URL rewriter](https://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/) works great. Would happily mark your previous comment as the solution if I could see how...